# Link with href and call function on new page

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, call

Is it possible to link to another web page and then call a function on that webpage? We have two pages and we would like to have a button that sends you to a specific part of the other page and would hence have to both send the user to the correct page and call a function on that page.

Is this at all possible? We do already have a document ready function and we do not want to go to this specific part of the page everytime we enter it, only if you come from the other page. Can you send some kind of variable with a link? Then we could write and if-statement to avoid calling our function every time the document loads.

We are coding in JavaScript and can use jQuery.

Comment: Sure.  Consider putting a hash property in the href, and then have the target page read the hash property.  In the document.ready, perform the action if you find the specified hash property in the URL.  `location.hash` reads hash properties from the URL.

Comment: Yes, that's possible so long as the receiving page can read either a hash, cookie, localStorage or a variable held in either POST or GET (in the URL). How far did you get when you tried to implement this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've done this several times using the method @Marc suggested in comments.

```
<a href="new_page#some_id">Link</a>
```

On the second page:

```
<div id="some_id">Content</div>
<script>
  if (window.location.hash === '#some_id') {
    call_function();
  }
</script>
```